# Slow parsing CSV file into a map of vectors

Tags: csv, clojure

I am trying to read in a CSV file and parse it into a map of vectors. So, the keys of the map are the column names from the CSV and the values of the map are vectors containing the columns of values from the CSV.

I use the built in [`clojure.data.csv`](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) for reading the file and even though the CSV file (found [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/nycflights13/flights.csv)) is only 32 MB, my code runs really quite slow.

```clj
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn csv->df [file-path]
  (with-open [reader (io/reader file-path)]
    (let [in-file (csv/read-csv reader)
          names (first in-file)
          data (rest in-file)]
      (zipmap (map keyword names) (apply mapv vector data)))))

(csv->df "data/flights.csv")
```

I suspect I'm doing something daft related to lazy sequences since I'm still getting to grips with them as a Clojure newb, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the issue.

Is it possible to restructure this function so that it doesn't run at a glacial pace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not benefitting from laziness, because transposing a matrix (which is what `apply map vector` is doing) can't be lazy. But you're not doing anything especially wrong. In my testing on my machine, 9 seconds is how long it takes just to call `read-csv` on this file and iterate over the results. Your function takes about twice as long. So your processing isn't exactly fast, but the best you could hope for would be a 50% speedup for the whole process, if you somehow managed to do all your post-processing in zero time.

I think these costs are just inevitable if you use clojure.data.csv. It's very convenient to have stuff packaged up into a nice tidy Clojure data structure for you, but it doesn't come for free. I tried FastCSV for comparison: it's around 20 times faster to read-and-discard the whole file, and similarly fast to produce a vector=of-vectors from the file. The transposition is still slow, but the whole process clocks in at 5s instead of 17s for your function. Here's what I wrote: inflexible and clunky, but it produces the same result and is simple enough. If performance really matters, you can fuse the transposition step, by never building a vector of rows to begin with, instead maintaining a separate vector for each column, and updating each of those for each row you encounter.

```
(defmacro row-fn [[arg] & body]
  (let [x (gensym 'arg)]
    `(reify java.util.function.Consumer
       (accept [this ~x]
         (let [~(with-meta arg {:tag `CsvRow}) ~x]
           ~@body)))))

(defn fastcsv->df [file-path]
  (let [headers (promise)
        csv (-> (CsvReader/builder)
                (.build (io/reader file-path))
                (.spliterator))
        rows (atom (transient []))]
    (.tryAdvance csv (row-fn [row]
                       (deliver headers (map keyword (.getFields row)))))
    (.forEachRemaining csv (row-fn [row]
                             (swap! rows conj! (.getFields row))))
    (zipmap @headers (apply map vector (persistent! @rows)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - it's much appreciated! Related to your comment about avoiding the transposition by parsing as I read: would you suggest doing this by reading the entire file (e.g., `slurp`) and then parsing the resulting string or by reading line by line?

Answer (score 4):

This is what [TMD](https://github.com/techascent/tech.ml.dataset) is for.

```clj
user> (require '[tech.v3.dataset :as ds])
nil
user> (time (def ds (ds/->dataset "https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/nycflights13/flights.csv")))
"Elapsed time: 2477.121908 msecs"
#'user/ds
```

That built the dataset in 2.5s, including ~1s of downloading it from the internet.

And, as you like, TMD datasets are logically maps of column name to column data:

```clj
user> (get ds "year")
#tech.v3.dataset.column<int16>[336776]
year
[2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013...]
```

And, as a bonus (and as you can see), the data is typed - the year column is 336776 primitive Java 16 bit `int`s. Which will occupy *much* less memory.

Comment: Fantastic! The typing together with the speed is amazing. Is it so fast because it's actually written in Java?

Comment: No - it's a clojure program. It's so fast because it's carefully written to be fast (: --- the thing you were doing was especially slow because it hit some of the slower paths of the Clojure datastructures. In general, the Clojure data structures are very very fast (surprising fast, imo), what you did was just 'unlucky', kinda. There are middle paths (that would use Clojure's `reduce`) that could mitigate it, but if you're doing columnar data, TMD is the way to go. hth

Comment: That's hugely helpful. TMD looks like it fits my use case perfectly. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome in - glad to have you.